# Flutter has wrong base URL running on subdirectories on server

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, cpanel

I'm trying to run my flutter app for a test on a server, so uploaded files on '/public_html/flutter/test_app/' and the domain is http://example.com
But when I'm trying to access and run the app, it gives me a console error :

```
GET http://example.com/main.dart.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

But it should look for main.dart.js file in `http://example.com/flutter/test_app/main.dart.js`
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your webserver to handle rewrites, see [flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies#configuring-your-web-server).
I had the same issue when I deployed to [netlify](https://app.netlify.com/), I was able to fix it by adding a _redirects file with

```
/*    /index.html   200
```